# How to do frosted glass effect with svg background?

Tags: html, css, svg, bulma

I'm trying to implement a frosted glass effect like the one seen [here](https://medium.com/hackernoon/how-to-do-css-only-frosted-glass-effect-e2666bafab91), over an svg background. I haven't had any luck so far, as while it works with bitmap images, with an svg background I just get a 100% transparent box.

I can't see why a blur filter would not be applied to an svg image and have not found answers when trying to search this.

This is my current attempt:

```css
html,
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' xmlns:svgjs='http://svgjs.com/svgjs' width='1440' height='560' preserveAspectRatio='none' viewBox='0 0 1440 560'%3e%3cg mask='url(%26quot%3b%23SvgjsMask1000%26quot%3b)' fill='none'%3e%3crect width='1440' height='560' x='0' y='0' fill='%230e2a47'%3e%3c/rect%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsSymbol1007' x='0' y='0'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsSymbol1007' x='720' y='0'%3e%3c/use%3e%3c/g%3e%3cdefs%3e%3cmask id='SvgjsMask1000'%3e%3crect width='1440' height='560' fill='white'%3e%3c/rect%3e%3c/mask%3e%3cpath d='M-1 0 a1 1 0 1 0 2 0 a1 1 0 1 0 -2 0z' id='SvgjsPath1001'%3e%3c/path%3e%3cpath d='M-3 0 a3 3 0 1 0 6 0 a3 3 0 1 0 -6 0z' id='SvgjsPath1003'%3e%3c/path%3e%3cpath d='M-5 0 a5 5 0 1 0 10 0 a5 5 0 1 0 -10 0z' id='SvgjsPath1002'%3e%3c/path%3e%3cpath d='M2 -2 L-2 2z' id='SvgjsPath1005'%3e%3c/path%3e%3cpath d='M6 -6 L-6 6z' id='SvgjsPath1004'%3e%3c/path%3e%3cpath d='M30 -30 L-30 30z' id='SvgjsPath1006'%3e%3c/path%3e%3c/defs%3e%3csymbol id='SvgjsSymbol1007'%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1001' x='30' y='30' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='30' y='90' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1003' x='30' y='150' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='30' y='210' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='30' y='270' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='30' y='330' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='30' y='390' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='30' y='450' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='30' y='510' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1001' x='30' y='570' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='90' y='30' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='90' y='90' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='90' y='150' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='90' y='210' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='90' y='270' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='90' y='330' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='90' y='390' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='90' y='450' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='90' y='510' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='90' y='570' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1001' x='150' y='30' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1001' x='150' y='90' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='150' y='150' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1003' x='150' y='210' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1001' x='150' y='270' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='150' y='330' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='150' y='390' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='150' y='450' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='150' y='510' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='150' y='570' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='210' y='30' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='210' y='90' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='210' y='150' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='210' y='210' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='210' y='270' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='210' y='330' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='210' y='390' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='210' y='450' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='210' y='510' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='210' y='570' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='270' y='30' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='270' y='90' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='270' y='150' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='270' y='210' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1003' x='270' y='270' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='270' y='330' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1001' x='270' y='390' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='270' y='450' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='270' y='510' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='270' y='570' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='330' y='30' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='330' y='90' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='330' y='150' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='330' y='210' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='330' y='270' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='330' y='330' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='330' y='390' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1003' x='330' y='450' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='330' y='510' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='330' y='570' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1006' x='390' y='30' stroke='%231c538e' stroke-width='3'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1006' x='390' y='90' stroke='%231c538e' stroke-width='3'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='390' y='150' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1003' x='390' y='210' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1006' x='390' y='270' stroke='%231c538e' stroke-width='3'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='390' y='330' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='390' y='390' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='390' y='450' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='390' y='510' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1003' x='390' y='570' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='450' y='30' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1003' x='450' y='90' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1003' x='450' y='150' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='450' y='210' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='450' y='270' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='450' y='330' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='450' y='390' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='450' y='450' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1003' x='450' y='510' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='450' y='570' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='510' y='30' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='510' y='90' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1006' x='510' y='150' stroke='%231c538e' stroke-width='3'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1003' x='510' y='210' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='510' y='270' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='510' y='330' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='510' y='390' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='510' y='450' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='510' y='510' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='510' y='570' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1001' x='570' y='30' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='570' y='90' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1006' x='570' y='150' stroke='%231c538e' stroke-width='3'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1001' x='570' y='210' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='570' y='270' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='570' y='330' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1003' x='570' y='390' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='570' y='450' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='570' y='510' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='570' y='570' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='630' y='30' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='630' y='90' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='630' y='150' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='630' y='210' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='630' y='270' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='630' y='330' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='630' y='390' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='630' y='450' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='630' y='510' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='630' y='570' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1003' x='690' y='30' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1006' x='690' y='90' stroke='%231c538e' stroke-width='3'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='690' y='150' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='690' y='210' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='690' y='270' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1003' x='690' y='330' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='690' y='390' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='690' y='450' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='690' y='510' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1003' x='690' y='570' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3c/symbol%3e%3c/svg%3e");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-size: cover;
}

.frost-bg{
  background: inherit;
  border-radius: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.frost-bg:before{
 content: “ ”;
 background: inherit;
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3000px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
 filter: blur(10px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.2/css/bulma.min.css">
  </head>


<div class="card frost-bg m-3">
  <div class="card-image">
    <figure class="image is-3by3">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/1346951/900x300?sig=1" alt="Placeholder image">
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="card-content ">
    <div class="media has-text-white">
      <div class="media-content has-text-white">
        <p class="title is-4 has-text-white">Frosted Glass Example</p>
        <p class="subtitle is-6 has-text-white">Text goes here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
  

</html>
```

What do I need to do to make this frosted glass effect work with responsive svg backgrounds?

Answer (score 1):

To apply the frosted glass effect, you have to use two CSS Properties -

- A transparent background
- `backdrop-filter`

The updated code is as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.2/css/bulma.min.css">
  </head>
  <style>
html, body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' xmlns:svgjs='http://svgjs.com/svgjs' width='1440' height='560' preserveAspectRatio='none' viewBox='0 0 1440 560'%3e%3cg mask='url(%26quot%3b%23SvgjsMask1000%26quot%3b)' fill='none'%3e%3crect width='1440' height='560' x='0' y='0' fill='%230e2a47'%3e%3c/rect%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsSymbol1007' x='0' y='0'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsSymbol1007' x='720' y='0'%3e%3c/use%3e%3c/g%3e%3cdefs%3e%3cmask id='SvgjsMask1000'%3e%3crect width='1440' height='560' fill='white'%3e%3c/rect%3e%3c/mask%3e%3cpath d='M-1 0 a1 1 0 1 0 2 0 a1 1 0 1 0 -2 0z' id='SvgjsPath1001'%3e%3c/path%3e%3cpath d='M-3 0 a3 3 0 1 0 6 0 a3 3 0 1 0 -6 0z' id='SvgjsPath1003'%3e%3c/path%3e%3cpath d='M-5 0 a5 5 0 1 0 10 0 a5 5 0 1 0 -10 0z' id='SvgjsPath1002'%3e%3c/path%3e%3cpath d='M2 -2 L-2 2z' id='SvgjsPath1005'%3e%3c/path%3e%3cpath d='M6 -6 L-6 6z' id='SvgjsPath1004'%3e%3c/path%3e%3cpath d='M30 -30 L-30 30z' id='SvgjsPath1006'%3e%3c/path%3e%3c/defs%3e%3csymbol id='SvgjsSymbol1007'%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1001' x='30' y='30' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='30' y='90' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1003' x='30' y='150' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='30' y='210' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='30' y='270' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='30' y='330' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='30' y='390' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='30' y='450' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='30' y='510' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1001' x='30' y='570' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='90' y='30' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='90' y='90' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='90' y='150' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='90' y='210' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='90' y='270' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='90' y='330' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='90' y='390' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='90' y='450' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='90' y='510' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='90' y='570' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1001' x='150' y='30' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1001' x='150' y='90' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='150' y='150' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1003' x='150' y='210' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1001' x='150' y='270' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='150' y='330' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='150' y='390' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='150' y='450' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='150' y='510' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='150' y='570' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='210' y='30' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='210' y='90' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='210' y='150' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='210' y='210' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='210' y='270' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='210' y='330' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='210' y='390' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='210' y='450' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='210' y='510' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='210' y='570' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='270' y='30' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='270' y='90' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='270' y='150' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='270' y='210' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1003' x='270' y='270' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='270' y='330' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1001' x='270' y='390' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='270' y='450' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='270' y='510' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='270' y='570' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='330' y='30' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='330' y='90' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='330' y='150' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='330' y='210' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='330' y='270' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='330' y='330' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='330' y='390' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1003' x='330' y='450' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='330' y='510' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='330' y='570' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1006' x='390' y='30' stroke='%231c538e' stroke-width='3'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1006' x='390' y='90' stroke='%231c538e' stroke-width='3'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='390' y='150' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1003' x='390' y='210' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1006' x='390' y='270' stroke='%231c538e' stroke-width='3'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='390' y='330' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='390' y='390' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='390' y='450' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='390' y='510' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1003' x='390' y='570' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='450' y='30' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1003' x='450' y='90' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1003' x='450' y='150' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='450' y='210' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='450' y='270' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='450' y='330' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='450' y='390' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='450' y='450' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1003' x='450' y='510' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='450' y='570' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='510' y='30' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='510' y='90' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1006' x='510' y='150' stroke='%231c538e' stroke-width='3'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1003' x='510' y='210' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='510' y='270' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='510' y='330' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='510' y='390' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='510' y='450' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='510' y='510' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='510' y='570' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1001' x='570' y='30' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='570' y='90' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1006' x='570' y='150' stroke='%231c538e' stroke-width='3'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1001' x='570' y='210' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='570' y='270' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='570' y='330' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1003' x='570' y='390' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='570' y='450' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='570' y='510' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='570' y='570' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='630' y='30' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='630' y='90' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='630' y='150' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='630' y='210' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='630' y='270' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='630' y='330' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='630' y='390' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='630' y='450' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='630' y='510' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='630' y='570' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1003' x='690' y='30' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1006' x='690' y='90' stroke='%231c538e' stroke-width='3'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='690' y='150' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='690' y='210' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='690' y='270' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1003' x='690' y='330' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='690' y='390' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='690' y='450' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='690' y='510' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1003' x='690' y='570' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3c/symbol%3e%3c/svg%3e");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}

.frost-bg{
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.25 );
  overflow: hidden;
  backdrop-filter: blur( 4.0px );
}

.frost-bg:before{
 content: “ ”;
 background: inherit;
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3000px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}
  </style>


<div class="card frost-bg m-3">
  <div class="card-image">
    <figure class="image is-3by3">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/1346951/900x300?sig=1" alt="Placeholder image">
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="card-content ">
    <div class="media has-text-white">
      <div class="media-content has-text-white">
        <p class="title is-4 has-text-white">Frosted Glass Example</p>
        <p class="subtitle is-6 has-text-white">Text goes here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
  

</html>
```

For Creating Awesome Frosted Glass Combinations you can have a look at this [website](https://glassmorphism.com/)

Comment: I was reluctant to use backdrop-filter as while it seemed like a solution, it seemed that it was only supported in newer versions of webkit based browsers. Firefox still has not implemented it, and older browsers won't display it at all. That's why I was hoping to adjust the solution from the link in my question to work with svg images, for max compatability. Your answer does work perfectly though in modern Chrome.

Comment: Yes..I understand that backdrop-filter isn't supported in older versions of browsers. That's a problem. I'm trying to find a better solution for max compatibility. If you find it please add it here for future references. ;)

Comment: If you don't want to use backdrop filter, you can use a second blurred version of the image in the background, appropriately transformed & clipped, as the background-image for your modal.

Comment: @MichaelMullany I think that's what John shows in his solution, but it doesn't seem to be working well with for me. I don't know if it is something to do with bulma, but it looks different from the backdrop-filter effect.

Answer (score 1):

So I was able to achieve this by adding an empty div `<div class="blurdiv"></div>` into `<div class="card frost-bg m-3">` as a child and adding this code to your CSS:

```
.blurdiv {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: inherit;
  filter: blur(10px);
  opacity: 0.75;
}


.media-content {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

This basically expands that empty div to take up 100% of the width and height of the card which I would style in a "glass" form. Then I used z-index to pull your `.media-content` above the `.blurdiv` div making it the background.

See it working here:

```css
html,
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' xmlns:svgjs='http://svgjs.com/svgjs' width='1440' height='560' preserveAspectRatio='none' viewBox='0 0 1440 560'%3e%3cg mask='url(%26quot%3b%23SvgjsMask1000%26quot%3b)' fill='none'%3e%3crect width='1440' height='560' x='0' y='0' fill='%230e2a47'%3e%3c/rect%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsSymbol1007' x='0' y='0'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsSymbol1007' x='720' y='0'%3e%3c/use%3e%3c/g%3e%3cdefs%3e%3cmask id='SvgjsMask1000'%3e%3crect width='1440' height='560' fill='white'%3e%3c/rect%3e%3c/mask%3e%3cpath d='M-1 0 a1 1 0 1 0 2 0 a1 1 0 1 0 -2 0z' id='SvgjsPath1001'%3e%3c/path%3e%3cpath d='M-3 0 a3 3 0 1 0 6 0 a3 3 0 1 0 -6 0z' id='SvgjsPath1003'%3e%3c/path%3e%3cpath d='M-5 0 a5 5 0 1 0 10 0 a5 5 0 1 0 -10 0z' id='SvgjsPath1002'%3e%3c/path%3e%3cpath d='M2 -2 L-2 2z' id='SvgjsPath1005'%3e%3c/path%3e%3cpath d='M6 -6 L-6 6z' id='SvgjsPath1004'%3e%3c/path%3e%3cpath d='M30 -30 L-30 30z' id='SvgjsPath1006'%3e%3c/path%3e%3c/defs%3e%3csymbol id='SvgjsSymbol1007'%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1001' x='30' y='30' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='30' y='90' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1003' x='30' y='150' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='30' y='210' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='30' y='270' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='30' y='330' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='30' y='390' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='30' y='450' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='30' y='510' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1001' x='30' y='570' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='90' y='30' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='90' y='90' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='90' y='150' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='90' y='210' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='90' y='270' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='90' y='330' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='90' y='390' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='90' y='450' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='90' y='510' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='90' y='570' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1001' x='150' y='30' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1001' x='150' y='90' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='150' y='150' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1003' x='150' y='210' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1001' x='150' y='270' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='150' y='330' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='150' y='390' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='150' y='450' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='150' y='510' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='150' y='570' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='210' y='30' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='210' y='90' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='210' y='150' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='210' y='210' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='210' y='270' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='210' y='330' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='210' y='390' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='210' y='450' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='210' y='510' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='210' y='570' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='270' y='30' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='270' y='90' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='270' y='150' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='270' y='210' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1003' x='270' y='270' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='270' y='330' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1001' x='270' y='390' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='270' y='450' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='270' y='510' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='270' y='570' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='330' y='30' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='330' y='90' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='330' y='150' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='330' y='210' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='330' y='270' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='330' y='330' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='330' y='390' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1003' x='330' y='450' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='330' y='510' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='330' y='570' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1006' x='390' y='30' stroke='%231c538e' stroke-width='3'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1006' x='390' y='90' stroke='%231c538e' stroke-width='3'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='390' y='150' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1003' x='390' y='210' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1006' x='390' y='270' stroke='%231c538e' stroke-width='3'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='390' y='330' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='390' y='390' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='390' y='450' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='390' y='510' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1003' x='390' y='570' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='450' y='30' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1003' x='450' y='90' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1003' x='450' y='150' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='450' y='210' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='450' y='270' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='450' y='330' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='450' y='390' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='450' y='450' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1003' x='450' y='510' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='450' y='570' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='510' y='30' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='510' y='90' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1006' x='510' y='150' stroke='%231c538e' stroke-width='3'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1003' x='510' y='210' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='510' y='270' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='510' y='330' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='510' y='390' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='510' y='450' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='510' y='510' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='510' y='570' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1001' x='570' y='30' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='570' y='90' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1006' x='570' y='150' stroke='%231c538e' stroke-width='3'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1001' x='570' y='210' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='570' y='270' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='570' y='330' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1003' x='570' y='390' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='570' y='450' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='570' y='510' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='570' y='570' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1005' x='630' y='30' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='630' y='90' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='630' y='150' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='630' y='210' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='630' y='270' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='630' y='330' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='630' y='390' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='630' y='450' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='630' y='510' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='630' y='570' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1003' x='690' y='30' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1006' x='690' y='90' stroke='%231c538e' stroke-width='3'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='690' y='150' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='690' y='210' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='690' y='270' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1003' x='690' y='330' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='690' y='390' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1002' x='690' y='450' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1004' x='690' y='510' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3cuse xlink:href='%23SvgjsPath1003' x='690' y='570' stroke='%231c538e'%3e%3c/use%3e%3c/symbol%3e%3c/svg%3e");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-size: cover;
}

.frost-bg{
  background: inherit;
  border-radius: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.frost-bg:before{
 content: “ ”;
 background: inherit;
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3000px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
 filter: blur(10px);
}


.blurdiv {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: inherit;
  filter: blur(10px);
  opacity: 0.75;
}


.media-content {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.2/css/bulma.min.css">
  </head>


<div class="card frost-bg m-3">
     <div class="blurdiv"></div>
  <div class="card-image">
    <figure class="image is-3by3">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/1346951/900x300?sig=1" alt="Placeholder image">
    </figure>
  </div>

  <div class="card-content ">
    <div class="media has-text-white">
      <div class="media-content has-text-white">
        <p class="title is-4 has-text-white">Frosted Glass Example</p>
        <p class="subtitle is-6 has-text-white">Text goes here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
   
</div>

</div>
  

</html>
```

Comment: Here I played with the code some more to get more of a glassy blurry look: https://jsfiddle.net/kt4ra97j/

Comment: The update is very interesting, and looks good in the snippet. I had trouble getting it running locally but I'm going to play with it some more and will accept or comment later today, thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi John, this is much better, but it looks much different from the backdrop-filter effect when I use it with a busier background. Do you know if it mnay be something to do with bulma, the css framework I am using, or if it is because backdrop-filter is something different?

Comment: Have you played with the opacity and blurs? Tinkering with those might help you achieve what you're looking for.  Can you post a jsfiddle of the "busier background" and first see if its replicable in jsfiddle. and if it is, then I can try some stuff if you want.

Comment: @Hi John, here is an example, I just changed the background from your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jhv6yg5m/ - Whatever I try and tweak, I can't make it seem blurred and 'frosted' in the same way backdrop-filter allows for. I would love to have a more compatible way to do that in pure css.

Comment: Is this closer to what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/f59sx1v8/

Comment: Hi John, not quite, I made a fiddle comparing your approach so you can see it right next to how backdrop-filter does it : https://jsfiddle.net/og812vd3/ - it's not previewing for me in the fiddle or in a SO snippet, but when placed in offline files they both display as they should.  Thanks for your help so far.